# jQuery Flot library label formatting and adjustment

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, flot

I would like to align the labels to right side of the pie chart. Currently it is on top of that. How do I change that?

Here is my code:

```
$json_ar = array(
                    ["label"=> "Management Frames", "data"=> $cnt_mgt, "color"=> "#50D050"],
                    ["label"=> "Control frames", "data"=> $cnt_control, "color"=> "#005CDE" ],
                    [ "label"=> "Data Frames", "data"=> $cnt_data, "color"=> "#A52A2A" ],
                    );

        //Control vs Data vs Management
        $json = encode_to_json($json_ar);
        $pie = "    <script type='text/javascript'>
                        $(function () {    $.plot($('#cdm_pie'),$json,{series: {pie: {radius:120, show: true, label:{show:true, radius:0.5, formatter:function(label,series){var percent = Math.round(series.percent);return('&nbsp;<b>'+percent+ '%</b>');} }}},legend:{show:true,}});    });
                        </script>";
        $tables["cdm"]="<div id='wrapper' style='display: inline-flex'>
                                <div id='cdm_pie' style='float: none;width: 250px;height: 250px;'></div>
                                $pie
                        </div>";
```

It is producing the following output :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kzqmt.png)

Also, how do I change the color of label from black to white?

Comment: Hi Akhil , Just change the width of the container. see the image i posted below..

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the width of the container.

Default position of legend marker is right.. so no need to worry..

[image]

Comment: By container, do you mean the div with id='wrapper'. Also, what should be the ideal width?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Got it :)